# How to avoid corrupted borders when presenting a modal controller in a UIPopOverController

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

I'm having an issue when presenting a modal view controller within a popover using the modal presentation style UIModalPresentationCurrentContext.

Something strange is happening to the border of the popover, here are some before/after screenshots:

Before presenting the modal controller:

[image]

And now once the modal controller has been displayed:

[image]

See how the border width on the left and top has changed? When the modal controller is dismissed the border width stays corrupted but if the whole popover is dismissed it displays correctly until the modal controller is shown again.

Here is the code we're using in a sample project that we've created to demonstrate the problem:

```
- (IBAction)showModalViewButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIButton *dismissButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    dismissButton.frame = CGRectMake(30, 30, 100, 25);
    [dismissButton setTitle:@"Dismiss" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [dismissButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissButtonTapped)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [viewController.view addSubview:dismissButton];
    viewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
    [viewController release];
}
```

Has anyone seen this before? any ideas?